How to Connect Spark to Unity Catalog on Kubernetes with Data Stored in MinIO?
I have a Unity Catalog server running on Kubernetes, and I want to connect my Spark code to handle queries. The data is stored in a MinIO bucket.
Here is my Spark session initialization code:
# Initialize Spark session with Unity Catalog support
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("UnityCatalogTest") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.my_catalog", "io.unitycatalog.spark.UCSingleCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.my_catalog.uri", unity_catalog_endpoint) \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.my_catalog.token", unity_catalog_token) \
    .config("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "my_catalog") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Example: List tables in a specific catalog and schema
catalog_name = "my_catalog"
schema_name = "catalog_sales_schema"

tables_df = spark.sql(f"SHOW SCHMEMAS IN {catalog_name}")
tables_df.show()

I got the following output:
+--------------------+
|           namespace|
+--------------------+
|       catalog_sales|
|catalog_sales_schema|
|         customer_sc|
|                demo|
|          local_demo|
|           my_schema|
|           newschema|
|  store_sales_schema|
|                test|
|    web_sales_schema|
+--------------------+

tables_df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES IN my_catalog.catalog_sales_schema")
tables_df.show()

+--------------------+---------------+-----------+
|           namespace|      tableName|isTemporary|
+--------------------+---------------+-----------+
|catalog_sales_schema|catalog_sales_1|      false|
+--------------------+---------------+-----------+

When I try to register the table, I get the following error:
spark.sql(f"""
    CREATE TABLE my_catalog.catalog_sales_schema.catalog_sales (
        cs_sold_date_sk INTEGER,
        cs_sold_time_sk INTEGER,
        cs_ship_date_sk INTEGER,
        cs_bill_customer_sk INTEGER,
        cs_bill_cdemo_sk INTEGER,
        cs_bill_hdemo_sk INTEGER,
        cs_bill_addr_sk INTEGER,
        cs_ship_customer_sk INTEGER,
        cs_ship_cdemo_sk INTEGER,
        cs_ship_hdemo_sk INTEGER,
        cs_ship_addr_sk INTEGER,
        cs_call_center_sk INTEGER,
        cs_catalog_page_sk INTEGER,
        cs_ship_mode_sk INTEGER,
        cs_warehouse_sk INTEGER,
        cs_item_sk INTEGER,
        cs_promo_sk INTEGER,
        cs_order_number LONG,
        cs_quantity INTEGER,
        cs_wholesale_cost DECIMAL(7,2),
        cs_list_price DECIMAL(7,2),
        cs_sales_price DECIMAL(7,2)
    )
    USING DELTA
    LOCATION 's3a://test/tpcds_10_delta/catalog_sales'
""")

Error:
{
"name": "AnalysisException",
"message": "\[SCHEMA_NOT_FOUND\] The schema `catalog_sales_schema` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog.
If you did not qualify the name with a catalog, verify the current_schema() output, or qualify the name with the correct catalog.
To tolerate the error on drop use DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS.",
"stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[49\], line 9
7 spark.sql("SHOW SCHEMAS").show()
8 # Create table with the specified schema
\----\> 9 spark.sql(f"""
10     CREATE TABLE my_catalog.catalog_sales_schema.catalog_sales (
11         cs_sold_date_sk INTEGER,
12         cs_sold_time_sk INTEGER,
13         cs_ship_date_sk INTEGER,
14         cs_bill_customer_sk INTEGER,
15         cs_bill_cdemo_sk INTEGER,
16         cs_bill_hdemo_sk INTEGER,
17         cs_bill_addr_sk INTEGER,
18         cs_ship_customer_sk INTEGER,
19         cs_ship_cdemo_sk INTEGER,
20         cs_ship_hdemo_sk INTEGER,
21         cs_ship_addr_sk INTEGER,
22         cs_call_center_sk INTEGER,
23         cs_catalog_page_sk INTEGER,
24         cs_ship_mode_sk INTEGER,
25         cs_warehouse_sk INTEGER,
26         cs_item_sk INTEGER,
27         cs_promo_sk INTEGER,
28         cs_order_number LONG,
29         cs_quantity INTEGER,
30         cs_wholesale_cost DECIMAL(7,2),
31         cs_list_price DECIMAL(7,2),
32         cs_sales_price DECIMAL(7,2)
33     )
34     USING DELTA
35     LOCATION 's3a://test/tpcds_10_delta/catalog_sales'
36 """)
}

What I've Tried:
I have tried to drop the schema and run all the basic SQL queries. Here is the code I used:
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a://test/tpcds_10_delta/catalog_sales")
df.write.format("delta") \
    .partitionBy("cs_bill_customer_sk") \
    .saveAsTable("my_catalog.catalog_sales_schema.catalog_sales_2")



schema = df.schema
spark.catalog.createTable(
    tableName="my_catalog.catalog_sales_schema.catalog_sales_2",
    path="s3a://test/tpcds_10_delta/catalog_sales",
    source="delta",
    schema=schema,
    description="This is a sample table"
)

Question:
How can I correctly create and register the table in Unity Catalog with the data stored in MinIO? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Are your versions correct? Spark 3.5.3 and Delta Lake 3.2.1 are required according to the Unity Catalog docs - https://docs.unitycatalog.io/integrations/unity-catalog-spark/

Yes, version's are correct.
